# ssis flat file source trim blank spaces

Tags: ssis

Is there any way i can trim the blank spaces when I read data from CSV file?

Thanks.

Comment: More details - I have send mail task for which I read email ids from CSV file. Now if CSV file has blank space in between 2 email ids then it throws error. So I need to avoid blank spaces either at flat file source or at send mail task. Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SendMail task requires ';' between email ids.  If you are building one large string to send your email to, consider using a script component to remove spaces and append a';' between each one.

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived column component after the CSV input, in the editor you should see columns in top-left so drag the email column into the editor and replace any spaces with empty strings. You should also set the derived column to replace the email column (Or you could add it as a new column, if you need that).